# Vue.js - emit only if the event hasn't been already been sent

Tags: vue.js

I have a search input.

Each keystroke on this input emit an event "search" ($emit Vue.js function).

I have another component listening on this event ($on Vue.js function), then call a search web service and display the result.

(the events are send on a bus, here a simple Vue instance).

This works well.

I want to emit the search event **only if no key press has been made for a delay**, let's say 200ms.
That way, if I quicly type a word in the search input, only one event will be sent. And if I'm slow, I still will have search results while typing.

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Start a timer at the start of the $on event, check for the time passed with an interval and then run the search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using underscore's `.debounce()` method for these purposes. Demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    query: ''
  },
  methods: {
    updateQuery: _.debounce(function (evt) {
      this.query = evt.target.value
      // Call your AJAX here. For example:
      // if (this.query.length) this.$store.dispatch('loadItems')
    }, 300),
    clearQuery () {
      this.query = ''
    }
  }
})
```

```css
[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <input
    type="text"
    @input="updateQuery"
    :value="query"
    placehorder="search..."
  >
  <button @click="clearQuery">clear</button>
  <p v-cloak>You are looking for {{ query }}</p>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/underscore@1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.4/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to be more effective, use Lodash. It is the same thing, but Lodash is modular, so you can add to your project only modules you need, and not the complete library. For .debounce() method is there separate javascript:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.17.4/debounce.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. And now, I can see this debounce function was quoted in the Vue.js documentation : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Comment: @CrieloueGilles Yes. Maybe it is used by everyone, i.e. AFAIK almost nobody create own implementation of debouncing function.